# How do search engines scrape instagram followers without getting blocked?

Tags: web-scraping, instagram, search-engine

I noticed that search engines have the number of followers and number of following from Instagram users, and they don't get blocked, how is that possible ?
As far as I know Instagram blocks bots after a certain number of requests.
I thought about them whitelisting the IPs from search engines, but that would be a lot work, so I'm assuming that's not the case.

Thank you !

Comment: Why it would be a lot of work? I don't think so. Surely, the whitelisting IPs is already an automatic task. There are many service which inform the IP provider if it belongs to `google` or `bing` etc for example https://tools.keycdn.com/geo?host=172.217.170.100. And i think instagram uses one of these services.

Comment: It would be a lot of work if they handle also new search engines, those search engines wouldn't have dedicated servers IPs.
But it's possible that they don't actually handle small search engines, and then it would make sense to just whitelist IPs.

Comment: @RAZAFINARIVOHanania thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.  Rather it is a question about how search engine bots crawl Instagram.